# How do I pass a filename to an emscripten-compiled node script on the command line?

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I'm having problems opening a user-specified file in a C program that has been compiled with emscripten (and is being run through node). Take this simple `cat`-like program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  char *filename;
  FILE *file;
  char buf[BUFSIZE];

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  file = fopen (argv[1], "r");
  while (fgets (buf, BUFSIZE, file))
    fputs (buf, stdout);

  fclose (file);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile this successfully with emscripten:

```
% /usr/local/src/emscripten/emcc tsrc/mycat.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
```

It runs, and expects an argument:

```
% node a.out.js 
Usage: /bin/this.program <filename>
```

But when I give it that argument, it barfs:

```
% node a.out.js somefile

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type
    at Function.APPLY_PREPARE (native)
    at Pointer_stringify (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:624:34)
    at _fopen (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:1917:14)
    at Object._main (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:2531:15)
    at Object.callMain (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:2585:25)
    at doRun (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:2624:20)
    at run (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:2647:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/mycat/a.out.js:2663:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
```

Here's the compiled JavaScript that's barfing:

```
function Pointer_stringify(ptr, /* optional */ length) {
  // Find the length, and check for UTF while doing so
  var hasUtf = false;
  var t;
  var i = 0;
  while (1) {
    t = HEAPU8[(((ptr)+(i))|0)];
    if (t >= 128) hasUtf = true;
    else if (t == 0 && !length) break;
    i++;
    if (length && i == length) break;
  }
  if (!length) length = i;
  var ret = '';
  if (!hasUtf) {
    var MAX_CHUNK = 1024; // split up into chunks, because .apply on a huge string can overflow the stack
    var curr;
    while (length > 0) {
      curr = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, HEAPU8.subarray(ptr, ptr + Math.min(length, MAX_CHUNK)));  // ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
      ret = ret ? ret + curr : curr;
      ptr += MAX_CHUNK;
      length -= MAX_CHUNK;
    }
    return ret;
  }
  var utf8 = new Runtime.UTF8Processor();
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    assert(ptr + i < TOTAL_MEMORY);
    t = HEAPU8[(((ptr)+(i))|0)];
    ret += utf8.processCChar(t);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The problem line from the error message (line 624) is the one with `String.fromCharCode.apply`.

Versions of relevant software:

```
% clang --version
clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
...
% node --version
v0.6.15
% python --version
Python 2.7.1
% /usr/local/src/emscripten/emcc --version
emcc (Emscripten GCC-like replacement) 1.3.6 (commit 17da251d334ce62d633d51f874b92e19ad9dbf45)
...
```

Eventually I want to load files in the browser environment too... I know that is a whole different ballgame, with file preloading etc.... for now I just want to get the command line working though!

Updated to add: after looking at https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Filesystem-Guide I tried preloading the file & get a different error:

```
% /usr/local/src/emscripten/emcc mycat.c --preload-file somefile
...
% node a.out.js somefile

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at...
```

Does this mean I need to run it in the browser?

Updated again to add:

```
% /usr/local/src/emscripten/emcc mycat.c -o mycat.html --preload-file README.md
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
% open mycat.html
```

Browser window shows "Preparing...", console log reveals error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/path/to/mycat.data. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. mycat.html:1
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 mycat.html:2816
still waiting on run dependencies: mycat.html:61
dependency: fp somefile mycat.html:61
dependency: datafile_mycat.data mycat.html:61
(end of list)
```

...and then the last four lines -- from 'still waiting on run dependencies: mycat.htm' onwards -- repeat every few seconds.

Do I need to be prepping these filesystem calls with FS on the javascript side, somehow?

Comment: Crossposted from https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/1120
_We don't support direct loading of files, everything must be in the virtual FS. You can use --embed-file or --preload-file for that.
In theory we could support direct loading of files in node since it has sync APIs for that, but no one has done the work yet._ --kripken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The error **Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP** simply means that your browser does not allow loading web pages from your hard disk directly.

Some browsers supports a command-line parameter to enable this, but I strongly suggest you simply run your web page on a simple HTTP server. This is easy to achieve using Python:

1. Open a command prompt in your app folder
2. Execute `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
3. Point your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`